# Refreshing Long Lived Facebook tokens with out user integration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a website integrated with facebook for posting and sharing contents. I have generated short lived user token and extend the token expiry by generating long lived using facebook graph api:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
client_id={app-id}&
client_secret={app-secret}&
fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

But this long lived token will get expired in 60 days after that it may required user interation for generate token again.
Please help me if any methods to extend this expire date with out user interation. I found one solution which recommends to recall the 'get long lived token again' but its not at all working as expected.
Please help me.

Comment: Of course no such methods exist, that would defeat the purpose of limiting your app’s access to a maximum of 60 days in the first place. You need to get a new short-lived user token first, and that requires user interaction. _“a website integrated with facebook for posting and sharing contents”_ - why do you need long-lived tokens for that anyway? Isn’t the user actively using your app, when you share/post in their name?

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks for the quick reply. We are maintaining these long lived token on user regitration in our website.So that when ever the user post any content on our website, it need to be reflected on connected facebook account also. Hence we are using the same long lived token for sharing/posting content on facebook using graph api.

Comment: When the user is actively doing stuff on your website, then all you would have to do is embed the JS SDK, and it will automatically see to it that you always have a valid short-lived token available. No need for any long-term tokens any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long lived token gets extended for each API call(per day) on posting, sharing contents or fetching token details. Hence you can extend the token expiry by using below token [debugging graph API call](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling):

```
GET /debug_token?
  input_token={input-token}&
  access_token={access-token}
```

As this solution evolved from the practical research, please test the  workflow before implementation.